# I am not able to send values to the baseclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

I have attached my code snippet in the following images. I have two classes here. One is the base class and another is sub class. Both classes have their own constructors. I have created objects of base class and sub class in a test class and have sent some values to the constructor. When I compile my program I get an error stating "constructor in class cannot be applied to given types" and reason as "actual and formal arguements differ in length". Why am I getting this error?

```
class base {
    int a;
    int b;
    base(int w, int x) {
        a = w;
        b = x;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("value of a is: " + a);
        System.out.println("value of b is: " + b);
    }
}
class sub extends base {
    int c;
    int d;
    sub(int y, int z) {
        c = y;
        d = z;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("value of a is: " + c);
        System.out.println("value of b is: " + d);
    }
}
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        base b1 = new base(10, 20);
        sub s1 = new sub(30, 40);
        b1.display();
        s1.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code as text and write down a proper question.

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy and paste the relevant code directly in the question. Provide enough code for us to be able to understand and replicate the issue. Also explain what your problem is and provide any error messages you may have

Comment: You shouldn't just give picture of code but text version, so we can run it. Also, what's your question?

Comment: you should add your code with issue that you are facing

Comment: Sordry i am a new user of this fourm. I found it difficult to add the code. Kepotx, my question is that program is not able to send parameters to base class constructor. When i compile my code i get error as" Constructor base in base class cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: @Krishnaprasad1 it's simple, copy-paste your code in the question, select all of it and press the fifth icon above the editor (or just press CTRL+K). Remove those images and post code as text, please.

Comment: It looks code has no issue.

Comment: but I am getting this error error: "constructor base in class base cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: You have an error in the constructor of class `sub`. Since the class `sub` is extending the class `base` and `base` has a non-zero-args-constructor the constructor of sublass `sub` has to call the `super` constructor:  `sub(int y, int z) { super(y, z); }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create default constructor in your base class.

your sub class constructor implicitly calls default constructor of base class.

if you want initialze your base class with sub class elements, you can call `super(int, int)` from sub class constructor.

In above example you can use as below,

```
 sub(int y, int z) {
  super(y,z);
    c = y;
    d = z;
}
```

in this case base class holds same values that passed to sub class.

if you dont call `super(int, int)` from sub class constructor, internally it calls default constructor of base class as below

```
sub(int y, int z) {
  super();
    c = y;
    d = z;
}
```

Comment: I modified the code. It compiled and executed without errors. Is it necessary do  create a default constructor while performing inheritance? Why should i explicitly create a default constructor in the base class?

Comment: @Krishnaprasad1 No... There is no need for default constructors. You just have to call `super();` depending on your defined constrcutors in the super class. In your case `sub(int x,int y){ super(x,y); }` is sufficient.

Comment: yes @L.Spillner, but that is when i create the object of sub class. But when I create the object of only super class? in your case i should create object of sub class and send the values to super class from sub class! but i need to directly send the values to super class by creating a super class object and not creating sub class object.

Comment: Also, I feel compelled to mention: this answer could have easily been put in a comment.

Comment: @Krishnaprasad1 The `base` class stays as is. No need for the default constructor. When a subclass is instantiated it needs to create it's super class(es) which means that if the base class doesn't have a non-zero constructor you have to call the `super(var1, var2, ...)` every time. I'll provide a proper answer shortly

Comment: @L.Spillner in your case i should create object of sub class and send the values to super class from sub class! but i need to directly send the values to super class by creating a super class object and not creating sub class object

Comment: _The base class stays as is._ The errors you got came up because you wanted to access a zero-argument constructor from your sub class. you can easily instantiate a sole `base object` by calling `base b = new base( 30 , 25 );`. Also note that the java coding convention states that classes should start with a capital letter -> `Base b = new  Base( 23,34);`.

Comment: @Krishnaprasad1 - if you want to directly sent the values to super class by creating super class object, it is must to have default constructor in your base class. because your sub class need it to initialize super class.

Comment: @L.Spillner Your suggestion about coding convention is noted. Now i got to know why the error occured. So the error is while creating sub class object as the sub class object is not able to call zero-arguement constructor. when i create sub class object, i should pass the value for super class? what if i dont want to send any value to super class?

Comment: @Ramesh: please look up [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) as it looks like you may be dealing with one